# Login with LinkedIn in Symfony

Tags: php, api, symfony, linkedin-api

I am Integrating the Login with LinkedIn in symfony framework using [Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client).But I'm getting **Could not get access token** Exception.

I'm attaching Screenshot of exception.

[image]

Following is the code near I'm getting error.

```
protected function fetchNewAccessToken()
    {
        $storage = $this->getStorage();
        $code = $this->getCode();

        if ($code !== null) {
            $accessToken = $this->getAccessTokenFromCode($code);
            if ($accessToken) {
                $storage->set('code', $code);
                $storage->set('access_token', $accessToken);

                return $accessToken;
            }

            // code was bogus, so everything based on it should be invalidated.    
            $storage->clearAll();
            throw new LinkedInApiException('Could not get access token');
        }

        // as a fallback, just return whatever is in the persistent                
        // store, knowing nothing explicit (signed request, authorization          
        // code, etc.) was present to shadow it (or we saw a code in $_REQUEST,    
        // but it's the same as what's in the persistent store)                    
        return $storage->get('access_token', null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd better suggest you to not to invent the bycicle. And the authentication bycicle is the worst thing ever, due to possible security bugs.

Just use already implemented OAuth clients, which supports the `LinkedIn` as an authentication provider.

I personnaly prefer the `HWIOAuthBundle`. It's pretty easy.

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

LinkedIn documentation:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/6c00622a9b87e475236949175f62bf4146c43216/Resources/doc/resource_owners/linkedin.md

Configuration

```
# app/config.yml

hwi_oauth:
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:           linkedin
            client_id:      <client_id>
            client_secret:  <client_secret>
            scope:          <scope>
```